# redirect to other page when I download via download link

Tags: python, http, web

For example, I can only download thr srt file on mouse click in this page:
http://www.addic7ed.com/show/95

When I type the download link http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/1/1792/0 in browser or try to get it via python, I finally get a new page.

Comment: not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server looks at the `Referer` HTTP header to check that the request for the `srt` file came from the page that links to it. You can use [Referer spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) to get around this:

If you run this cURL command, you get back the response you are looking for:

```
curl 'http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/8/1736/1' -H 'Referer: http://www.addic7ed.com/show/95'
```

The same using a Python script:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/8/1736/1", headers={"Referer":"http://www.addic7ed.com/show/95"});
print response.text

> python addic7ed.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much